# Asynctask doesn't reach onPostExecute even though it is initialized in the UI thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I am making an application which queries a database using an asynctask in a separate class. This class takes a string, passes the string (which should be a query) and gets the result as a ResultSet. This ResultSet should then be passed down to onPostExecute, where it uses an interface to get the result back onto the main thread. However, using log commands I have found that the asynctask never reaches the onPostExecute. Could anybody help me with this?

My Asynctask Class (getMyResults() is no longer used, and code into the doInBackground is irrelevant):

edit: edit

```
public class DBConnector extends AsyncTask <String, Void, ResultSet> {

    private Connection con;
private Statement st;
private ResultSet rs;
public CallBackListener DBlistener;



public ResultSet getMyResults(){
    return rs;
}

//public


@Override
protected ResultSet doInBackground(String... params) {

String Query = params[0];
        System.out.println("Starting DBConnector");

//Code to get the database connection working

    try{
        rs = st.executeQuery(Query);
        System.out.println("Records from Database");
        /*
        while(rs.next()){

            String StudentID = rs.getString("StudentID");
            String StudentName = rs.getString("StudentName");
            String StudentPassword = rs.getString("StudentPassword");
            System.out.println("Student ID: "+StudentID+"   Student Name: "+StudentName+"    Student Password: "+StudentPassword);
        }
        */
    }catch(Exception ex){
        System.out.println(ex);
    }

    System.out.println("Finished DBConnector");


    return rs;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(ResultSet rs) {
    System.out.println("THIS IS WHERE IT ALL GOES WRONG");
    DBlistener.processFinish(rs);
}
```

}

And my Interface (in it's own file - is that how it's meant to be?):

```
public interface CallBackListener {
   void processFinish(ResultSet output);
        }
```

Finally my activity, I've left out all the irrelevant code:

```
public class CheckTimetable extends Activity implements CallBackListener {
    ResultSet rs= null;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_check_timetable);

        try {
            Class.forName("android.os.AsyncTask");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

// this was added as a suggestion to fix my problem, but to no avail.

```
    btnBuildTimetable.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                BuildTable(rows, cols, "A"); //need mapping system to get TutorID from spinner and send it here
```

// in my orginal code rows and cols are integer obtained from 2 edittexts
                }

```
        }
    });

}


private void BuildTable(int rows, int cols, String GivenTutorID){
DBConnector connect = new DBConnector();
String StudentID = "";
String TutorID = "";
String VenueLocation = "";
String LessonDate = "";
String LessonStartTime = "";
String LessonEndTime = "";
connect.execute("SELECT * FROM Lessons WHERE Lessons.TutorID = '"+ GivenTutorID + "';");
connect.DBlistener = this;//should use TutorID here
    /*
try {
    Thread.sleep(5000);//just used so that the resultset doesn't get no results - waits for connect.execute to finish.
}
catch (Exception e) {}
*/
    System.out.println("WE GO IN BOYS");
while (rs == null ){
    try {
        Thread.sleep(100);
    } catch (Exception e){}
}

rs = connect.getMyResults();

for (int i=1; i<=rows; i++){
    TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
    row.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    for (int j=1; j<=cols;j++){
        try {
            while (rs.next()) {
                StudentID = rs.getString("StudentID");
                TutorID = rs.getString("TutorID");
                VenueLocation = rs.getString("VenueLocation");
                LessonDate = rs.getString("LessonDate");
                LessonStartTime = rs.getString("LessonStartTime");
                LessonEndTime = rs.getString("LessonEndTime");
            }
        }catch(Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("caught exception");
        }
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        tv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cell_shape);
        tv.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        tv.setText(LessonDate);
        System.out.println(LessonDate);
        System.out.println("Cell set");

            row.addView(tv);

        }
tblTutorTimetable.addView(row);
    }
    }
        @Override
        public void processFinish(ResultSet output) {
            rs = output;
            System.out.println("WE MADE IT");
        }
```

When the BuildTable button is pressed, it goes through the code, executes the asynctask then waits until the ResultSet is not null. The 2nd thread (the asynctask) gets all the way through until the end of the doInBackground, where nothing happens after and the UI thread remains frozen.

Any help at all regarding this or the interface would be fantastic!

Answer (score 0):

> When the BuildTable button is pressed, it goes through the code, executes the asynctask then waits until the ResultSet is not null. The 2nd thread (the asynctask) gets all the way through until the end of the doInBackground, where nothing happens after and the UI thread remains frozen.

Don't wait for your asynctask yourself. Especially don't block the UI thread with `Thread.sleep()`.

Async task `onPostExecute()` is run on the UI thread and it never gets a chance to run when you're blocking the thread yourself.

Instead, use async tasks in an asyncrhronous manner: let the UI thread do whatever it's doing and return control to the UI thread looper/handler, and update the UI with the async task results in `onPostExecute()`.

Comment: But my UI can only do what it needs to do with the ResultSet. At first I had a simple getter to return the time, but again that was a poor solution as I had to simply freeze the UI thread for a set amount of time, to give the AsyncTask time to get results from my cloud database. How can I get the ResultSet retrieved from AsyncTask back as soon as it is retreved? Thanks in advance